# Splash screen skipped and screens don't load properly

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a flutter app I am developing. When I run the app in debug mode it works really well. However when i export the APK version there's a very weird thing that happens. When I tap on the app to open it, sometimes it loads well with the splash screen and everything displays correctly.
Other times when I tap on the app icon it loads without the splash screen and the whole app is a mess.

[image: When it loads with the splash screen]

[image: When it loads without the splash screen]

The screenshots above, the first image is the result when the splash screen loads (hence giving time for resources to be loaded). The second image is when the splash screen is skipped, it still takes the same time to display the app content but then with no resources loaded and no styling.

I have no idea why this happens as it only happens when I export the app as an APK.

Comment: can you show as the code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the app with

> flutter run --release

Or you could run the app (with the exported apk) and run

> flutter attach

This will show the app logs while running

Answer (score 0):

Have you build apk release ?
try to build release app by run

```
flutter build apk --release
```

If your problem is not solved Share your project file or github link to better understand your problem and solve it for you